# How to find a pair of distinct fields of an object from a collection

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, grouping

I have a class

```
class Vehicle {
    VehicleType type;
    String regCode;
}
```

and enum

```
enum VehicleType {
    CAR,
    BUS
}
```

If I have a list of vehicle with values like this

```
 [
 {type: CAR, regCode: "AB11"},
 {type: BUS, regCode: "XY12"},
 {type: CAR, regCode: "AB22"}, 
 {type: BUS, regCode: "AB22"}
 ]
```

How can i get the distinct types and regCodes using one stream?

I expect something like this :

```
Pair<Set<VehicleType>, Set<String>> result = {[CAR, BUS], ["AB11", "XY12", "AB22"]}
```

Any other format is also ok.

Comment: You would need to change only the Collectors.toSet() (I misread your POJO and thought it was a String which you would need to get the enum from). Also, you could probably use the BiFunction merger to return a custom Pair class also instead of a Map

Answer (score 1):

Bisecting the vehicles in a single stream is doable, but the result would not be pretty.

I would go for a simple loop

```java
public static Pair<Set<VehicleType>, Set<String>> bisect(Iterable<Vehicle> vehicles)
{
    final var types = new HashSet<VehicleType>();
    final var regCodes = new HashSet<String>();
    for (final Vehicle vehicle : vehicles)
    {
        types.add(vehicle.type);
        regCodes.add(vehicle.regCode);
    }
    return new Pair(types, regCodes);
}
```